# s-function as a bus selector

Tags: matlab, structure, simulink, s-function

i need an idea how to make an s-function behave as a bus selector. i have an structure being given as a input to an s-function . this structure has 283 elements (maybe more in future) and is being supplied as  a bus. i want the s-function to output the individual elements of the structure (and thus act like a bus selector). Ofcourse I can do this easily with manual typing :

```
y0[0]=u0->arguemtn;
y0[0]=u0->speedx; % and so on till 283
```

but then i need to know the name of the all the structure element and also need to enter them manually. is there a way i just need to use a simple for loop and allocate individual element inputs to outputs of the s-function.

you can just give me the hint since i am just stuck here

**UPDATE**

after the suggested answer i tried to write something like this.

```
int number_of_elements,i;
char field_name;
number_of_elements= mxGetNumberOfFields(u0[0]);

for(i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
{
    field_name=mxGetFieldNameByNumber(u0[0], i);
    yi[0]=u0->field_name;
}
```

but first how can i make y1 y2 y3 and so on as a part of the loop. ofcourse i can't write yi since its an entirely different variable. also this part I have written in the Code Description part of the s-function builder which I think is wrong again. can anybody suggest me what i should do exactly.

another important point is that I am sending the structure with fields which are of different datatypes (like uint8,uint16,single) and thus i also need to determine the input datatype. how can that be possible and how i can set this datatype to my output in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a C-code S-Function, in which case all of the C-mex API routines are available.

There are a variety functions for interrogating the Structure, determining the field names, and manipulating them.  See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/access-data.html) for a link to them, including [mxGetField](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetfield.html) and [mxGetNumberOfFields](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberoffields.html).  Start by looking at and working through the example discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-structures-and-cell-arrays.html).

Comment: i have a doubt regarding this. since i won't know the number of fields in my structure and thus I won't know the number of outputs in my s-function builder block, how can i make this dynamic?

Comment: In the S-Function initialization you use the appropriate API function to interrogate the structure (input as a parameter) to determine the number of fields, then you use other appropriate API functions to set the number of outputs (and other properties).

Comment: hey i updated my question. while i was going through the s-function documentation i found out this. that the s-function's limitation is that it doesn't support bus signals                                                                                          http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/s-function-limitations.html                   so any idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: With what you are doing here, you should be using a hand written c-mex S-function, which do support busses.